# Android null pointer exception in FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

//Here is the java code

```
private FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options;
    private FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector;

 options=new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
                    .build();

            detector= FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options);
            Dexter.withActivity(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                            showCamera();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                            common.showtoast("you must accept permission",BarcodescannerActivity.this);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

                        }
                    }).check();
```

I am implementing firebase QRcode scanner using ML-Kit in my android application.when i try to execute the code i am getting null pointer exception

Note:Here is the exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision.getVisionBarcodeDetector(com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions)' on a null object reference

Comment: It looks like `FirebaseVision.getInstance()` is returning null, which probably should never happen.  If you are certain that you've integrated the SDK correctly in your app, and your SDK is at the latest version, file a bug with Firebase support with complete steps to reproduce the error. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: ok thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you haven't set up Firebase? The first step in the "Before you begin" section https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes

Comment: Is that a rhetoric or an actual  question?